# Copy remote-server's CLI output to clipboard on the client

Tags: clipboard

How to copy remote-server's CLI output to clipboard on the client?

e.g.

```
Windows Terminal →→→SSH→→→ Ubuntu
 (copy to                   (CLI
 clipboard  ←←←←←←←←←←←←←←  output
   here)                     here)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout *xclip* on the Ubuntu Server type in `man xclip` to take a look at the manual. You may want to read this article https://opensource.com/article/19/7/xclip if the manual pages aren't enough.

If that doesn't help take another look at the Arch Linux Wiki https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Copying_text_from_a_terminal#Terminals_without_CLIPBOARD_selection under Section 3.1 should apply to Ubuntu Server too.